# How can I detect changes to files from Windows?

Tags: windows

I want to track changes for files inside a directory, and notify web services whenever they change.

On a Mac, I know I can react to [file system events](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060817044149264), like creating it, modifying it, etc.

Which would be the best way to do this in Windows?
Which language do you advise for this? (I will be building a basic UI for it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native (C++/C) API is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx).  In .Net (C# etc) this is encapsulated in the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.  C# is much easier to program for, there is some sample code at that URL.

These APIs are both subject to occasional missed events.  There's no solution to this that I am aware of, not any easy alternative.  If your directory is not changing that often, it likely will work just fine for you.

Answer (score 4):

C# has a class `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` which will probably do what you want. More details [on the MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). For C++, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107275/does-anyone-have-a-filesystemwatcher-like-class-in-c-winapi).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris, and the reference to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

With Java we can Use the **WatchService** to detect the kind of events have occurred in a specific file or even directory.

The Implementation is easy as You can just get WatchService from FileSystem as follow:

**1- Get the WatchService:** WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

**2- Use the WatchService in Your file:**

FILE_LOCATION.register(watchService, *StandardWatchEventKinds.**ENTRY_MODIFY***, *StandardWatchEventKinds.**ENTRY_DELETE***, *StandardWatchEventKinds.**ENTRY_CREATE***)

After all, You can see all kind of events that had occurred in Your file like above: **StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY** which mean that your file has been modified.

For more details check the link below:

https://github.com/PascoalBayonne/Exercise/blob/master/src/nio/directory/watching/DirectoryWatching.java