# FindNextPrinterChangeNotification returns NULL for ppPrinterNotifyInfo

Tags: c++, c, winapi, printing, print-spooler-api

I'm stuck on problem were I would like to ask for some help:

I have the task to print some files of different types using ShellExecuteEx with the "print" verb and need to guarantee print order of all files. Therefore I use FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification and FindNextPrinterChangeNotification to monitor the events PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB and PRINTER_CHANGE_DELETE_JOB using two different threads in the background which I start before calling ShellExecuteEx as I don't know anything about the application which will print the files etc. The only thing I know is that I'm the only one printing and which file I print. My solution seems to work well, my program successfully recognizes the event PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB for my file, I even verify that this event is issued for my file by checking what is give to me as additional info by specifying JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT.

The problem now is with the event PRINTER_CHANGE_DELETE_JOB, where I don't get any addition info about the print job, though my logic is exactly the same for both events: I've written one generic thread function which simply gets executed with the event it is used for. My thread is recognizing the PRINTER_CHANGE_DELETE_JOB event, but on each call to FindNextPrinterChangeNotification whenever this event occured I don't get any addition data in ppPrinterNotifyInfo. This works for the start event, though, I verified using my logs and the debugger. But with PRINTER_CHANGE_DELETE_JOB the only thing I get is NULL.

I already searched the web and there are some similar questions, but most of the time related to VB or simply unanswered. I'm using a C++ project and as my code works for the ADD_JOB-event I don't think I'm doing something completely wrong. But even MSDN doesn't mention this behavior and I would really like to make sure that the DELETE_JOB event is the one for my document, which I can't without any information about the print job. After I get the DELETE_JOB event my code doesn't even recognize other events, which is OK because the print job is done afterwards.

The following is what I think is the relevant notification code:

```
WORD                        jobNotifyFields[1]  = {JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT};
PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE pnot[1]             = {JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE, 0, 0, 0, 1, jobNotifyFields};
PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS      pno                 = {2, 0, 1, pnot};
HANDLE                      defaultPrinter      = PrintWaiter::openDefaultPrinter();
HANDLE                      changeNotification  = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(   defaultPrinter,
                                                                                        threadArgs->event,
                                                                                        0, &pno);
[...]
DWORD waitResult = WAIT_FAILED;
while ((waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(changeNotification, threadArgs->wfsoTimeout)) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, L"Irgendein Druckereignis im Thread zum Warten auf Ereignis " << LogStringConv(threadArgs->event) << L" erkannt.");

[...]
    PPRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO    notifyInfo  = NULL;
    DWORD                   events      = 0;
    FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(changeNotification, &events, NULL, (LPVOID*) &notifyInfo);
    if (!(events & threadArgs->event) || !notifyInfo || !notifyInfo->Count)
    {
        LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, L"unpassendes Ereignis " << LogStringConv(events) << L" ignoriert");
        FreePrinterNotifyInfo(notifyInfo);
        continue;
    }
[...]
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could give some hints on why I don't get any data regarding the print job. Thanks!

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86657&stqc=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think is going on:

I observe two events in two different threads for the start and end of each print job. With some debugging and logging I recognized that FindNextPrinterChangeNotification doesn't always return only the two distinct events I've notified for, but some 0-events in general. In those cases FindNextPrinterChangeNotification returns 0 as the events in pdwChange. If I print a simple text file using notepad.exe I only get one event for creation of the print job with value 256 for pdwChange and the data I need in notifyInfo to compare my printed file name against and comparing both succeeds. If I print a pdf file using current Acrobat Reader 11 I get two events, one has pdwChange as 256, but gives something like "local printdatafile" as the name of the print job started, which is obviously not the file I printed. The second event has a pdwChange of 0, but the name of the print job provided in notifyInfo is the file name I used to print. As I use FreePDF for testing pruproses, I think the first printer event is something internal to my special setup.

The notifications for the deletion of a print job create 0 events, too. This time those are sent before FindNextPrinterChangeNotification returns 1024 in pdwChange, and timely very close after the start of the print job. In this case the exactly one generated 0 event contains notifyInfo with a document name which equals the file name I started printing. After the 0 event there's exactly one additional event with pdwChange of 1024, but without any data for notifyInfo.

I think Windows is using some mechanism which provides additional notifications for the same event as 0 events after the initial event has been fired with it's real value the user notified with, e.g. 256 for PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB. On the other hand it seems that some 0 events are simply fired to provide data for an upcoming event which then gets the real value of e.g. 1024 for PRINTER_CHANGE_DELETE_JOB, but without anymore data because that has already been delivered to the event consumer with a very early 0 event. Something like "Look, there's more for the last events." and "Look, something is going to happen with the data I already provide now." Implementing such an approach my prints now seem to work as expected.

Of course what I wrote doesn't fit to what is documented for FindNextPrinterChangeNotification, but it makes a bit of sense to me. ;-)

Comment: Any reason why this explanation has been down voted? Even MSDN says something about collapsing events, multiple event data within one notification etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for overflows or errors.

The documentation for [FindNextPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says this:

> If the PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DISCARDED bit is set in the Flags member of
>   the PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO structure, an overflow or error occurred, and
>   notifications may have been lost. In this case, no additional
>   notifications will be sent until you make a second
>   FindNextPrinterChangeNotification call that specifies
>   PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH.

You need to check for that flag and do as described above, and you should also be checking the return code from `FindNextPrinterChangeNotification`.

Comment: I already added error checking, but it didn't change anything regarding my problem and no data has ever been discarded. Discarded events are always an error in my case, too, as I need to know if a print job has been removed and this event could have been discarded as well and would never be send again.