# How to know when a new file is added to the file system in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, boost

I want to monitor addition and renaming of files in Windows using C++. I searched on Google but cant find any useful info.

I am open to using Winapi , boost or Qt.

Comment: What's the scope? Doing this on the network level would be difficult. HDD on local host a little easier; perhaps.

Comment: I want to monitor on HDD and external drives like pendrive attached to local host.

Comment: OK; Jochen's answer (+1) has legs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use File system watcher. See also:

- [How do I make my program watch for file modification in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931093/how-do-i-make-my-program-watch-for-file-modification-in-c)

which internally uses ReadDirectoryChangesW:

- [Does anyone have a FileSystemWatcher-like class in C++/WinAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107275/does-anyone-have-a-filesystemwatcher-like-class-in-c-winapi)

Answer (score 2):

The solution in Qt would be [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html).

Comment: QFileSystemWatcher doesn't tell u the filename that was added/changed. Moreover that can't monitor recursively.